# Synchronizing rest async responses to a collection in Java

Tags: java, rest, asynchronous

Didn't find similar question here so decided to ask for help.
In Java 8 I have method *getEmployees* with list of employee ids as input. Within this method I'm sending async rest-api requests to another service to get each employee information by its id. And I'm trying to save responses as dto to list and return this list as a result of *getEmployees*. Here is the code:

```
private List<EmployeeDto> getEmployeeDtos(List<String> employeesIds) {

List<EmployeeDto> result = new ArrayList<>();
for (String id : employeesIds) {
    String empUrl = dataUrl.concat(id);

    ListenableFuture<ResponseEntity<String>> futureResponse = asyncRestTemplate.exchange(
                    empUrl,
                    HttpMethod.GET,
                    StringUtils.isEmpty(token) ? createRequest() : createRequest(token),
                    String.class
                );
    futureResponse.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<ResponseEntity<String>>() {
                    @SneakyThrows
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
                        result.add(null);
                    }

                    @SneakyThrows
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(ResponseEntity<String> stringResponseEntity) {
                        ResponseEntity<String> response = futureResponse.get();
                        EmployeeDto dto = objectMapper.readValue(response.getBody(), new TypeReference<EmployeeDto>() {
                        });
                        result.add(dto);
                    }
                });

    while (result.size() != employeesIds.size()) {
    }
    return result;
}
```

I don't really like that *while* loop for synchronizing result collection before return result. Is there any ideas how to return whole result collection properly without while loop in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Count callback calls using CountDownLatch:

```
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(employeesIds.size);
....
result.add(null);
latch.countDown();
....
result.add(dto);
latch.countDown();
...
if (!latch.await(20,  TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
   throw new TimeoutException();
}
return result;
```

Besides, `result` must be a synchronized collection, or callback methods must be synchronized.